# Custom animation between sections by fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, webgl, fullpage.js

Is it possible to implement [such animation](https://www.cher-ami.tv/en) by fullpage.js extension behind sections on scroll (destroyed effect)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at the moment.
The closest you can get is by using the [Water Effect extension instead](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/water-effect.html).